# adding to a double in a switch statement

Tags: java

I'm creating a switch wrapped in a while, for a homework assignment. Everything works except the adding to the `totalPrice` double, I've tried using

`totalPrice += priceA;` and 
`totalPrice = totalPrice + priceA;`

Here's my dump, I know it's something super simple, but my googling and documentation have turned up nil.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coffee {
    public static double priceA = 1.99;
    public static double priceE = 2.99;
    public static double priceL = 3.99;
    public static double totalPrice = 0;
    public static int custChoice;
    public static int counter =1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu();
         while (counter <3 && custChoice !=0) {
             menu();
             switch (custChoice) {
                 case '1':
                     totalPrice = totalPrice +priceA;
                     return;
                 case '2':
                     totalPrice = totalPrice +priceE;
                     return;
                 case '3':
                     totalPrice = totalPrice +priceL;
                     return;
                 case '0':
                     break;
                 default:
                     System.out.println("Your total is $" + totalPrice);
             }
             counter++;
         }
    }

    public static void menu() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        System.out.println("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);

        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("  (1) American    1.99       ");
        System.out.println("  (2) Espresso    2.99       ");
        System.out.println("  (3) Latte       3.99       ");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(" Please make a selection \n\t or enter 0 to total and quit.");
        custChoice = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Help my StackOverflow! You're my only hope.

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what is _actually_ happening? You have return statements in all of your cases except 0. This means that if the user chooses anything other than 0, the program is going to terminate.

Comment: "Please make a selection \n\t or enter 0 to total and quit."

There is a counter and if you choose 0 or any other [will print the total], and counter is => 3 than you will exit. On the other hand you try to compare integer to char in switch case...

Comment: How can you tell? You `return` from `main`... that terminates the program.

Comment: It seems that you use "return" instead of "break" in the switch statement, doesn't it ?

Comment: replace case '1': to case 1: and so on..

Comment: and replace case '0' section to:
case 0: 
        System.out.println("Your total is $" + totalPrice);
        return;

Comment: and remove "&& custChoice !=0" from while statement

Comment: This is a tangent to the original question, but... When I see `double` being used in conjunction with currency-related words like `price`, I cringe just a little bit. You shouldn't be using floating-point data types to represent anything related to money. Identify the smallest unit of currency in your system, and let the integral value `1` represent that unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the default-case for some basic input-error-handling, since the Code it is containing will be executed when neither of the other cases(0,1,2,3) was detected.

so, as others have mentioned, move the summation of the total price to case 0 and end that case with a return-statement which will end the execution of your program.

Further more insert some warning-text for the user in your default-case and tell that the Input was wrong.
To prevent logic-issues you should decrement Counter by one, since the user hasn't bought anything in this Iteration of the while-loop and it will be incremented by one at the end of the Loop

edit:
I think the answer from Dániel Kis is already really good, but has no content for the default-case.
I took his solution and expanded it:

```
public class Coffee {
public static double priceA = 1.99d;
public static double priceE = 2.99d;
public static double priceL = 3.99d;
public static double totalPrice = 0d;
public static int custChoice;
public static int counter =1;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu();
    while (counter <3) {
        switch (custChoice) {
            case 1:
                totalPrice = totalPrice +priceA;
                break;
            case 2:
                totalPrice = totalPrice +priceE;
                break;
            case 3:
                totalPrice = totalPrice +priceL;
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Your total is $" + totalPrice);
                return;
            default:
                System.out.println("This Option is not available, please try again!");
                counter--;
                break;
        }
        counter++;
        menu();
    }
}

public static void menu() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
    System.out.println("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);

    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    System.out.println("  (1) American    1.99       ");
    System.out.println("  (2) Espresso    2.99       ");
    System.out.println("  (3) Latte       3.99       ");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(" Please make a selection \n\t or enter 0 to total and quit.");
    custChoice = input.nextInt();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

try this, you will exit after 3rd choice

```
public class Coffee {
    public static double priceA = 1.99d;
    public static double priceE = 2.99d;
    public static double priceL = 3.99d;
    public static double totalPrice = 0d;
    public static int custChoice;
    public static int counter =1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu();
        while (counter <3) {
            switch (custChoice) {
                case 1:
                    totalPrice = totalPrice +priceA;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    totalPrice = totalPrice +priceE;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    totalPrice = totalPrice +priceL;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Your total is $" + totalPrice);
                    return;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            counter++;
            menu();
        }
    }

    public static void menu() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        System.out.println("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);

        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("  (1) American    1.99       ");
        System.out.println("  (2) Espresso    2.99       ");
        System.out.println("  (3) Latte       3.99       ");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(" Please make a selection \n\t or enter 0 to total and quit.");
        custChoice = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a little explanation might be helpful: with the `returns` in the `switch` was exiting the `main` method and ending the program, while with `break` the program stays in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes around the numbers you are checking, other wise the switch statement is looking for chars. Also, it seems like maybe you want to be using `break` instead of `return` ?

```
         switch (custChoice) {
             case 1:
                 totalPrice = totalPrice +priceA;
                 break;
             case 2:
                 totalPrice = totalPrice +priceE;
                 break;
             case 3:
                 totalPrice = totalPrice +priceL;
                 break;
             case 0:
                 break;
             default:
                 System.out.println("Your total is $" + totalPrice);
         }
```

Comment: `return` -> `break`

Comment: It won't print total if you choose 0!

Answer (score 1):

Is CustChoice a string or an int? Or is this relevant? It looks like in the while condition you're checking it as an int and in the switch as a string if it is an int the switch should just go to default.  Wasn't able to test it but worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
public class Coffee {
        public static double priceA = 1.99;
        public static double priceE = 2.99;
        public static double priceL = 3.99;
        public static double totalPrice = 0;
        public static int custChoice;
        public static int counter = 1;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             while (counter<=3) {
                 menu();
                 switch (custChoice) {
                     case 1:
                         totalPrice += priceA;
                         break;
                     case 2:
                         totalPrice += priceE;
                         break;
                     case 3:
                         totalPrice += priceL;
                         break;
                     case 0:
                         System.out.println("Your total is $" + totalPrice);
                         return;
                     default:
                         System.out.println("Unrecognised command");
                 }
                 counter++;
             }
        }

        public static void menu() {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
            System.out.println("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);

            System.out.println("-----------------------------");
            System.out.println("  (1) American    1.99       ");
            System.out.println("  (2) Espresso    2.99       ");
            System.out.println("  (3) Latte       3.99       ");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(" Please make a selection \n\t or enter 0 to total and quit.");
            custChoice = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

First you're calling menu(), and then you're calling menu() again after that. You only need to call it once as while loop will always execute due to counter starting off as 1.

Make sure you're checking the cases as integers and not chars and make sure to break out of the switch statement and not return like you have.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It will print the total if you choose other than 0-3

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that youre checking for chars in your switch. replace those with the correct numeric values. Also use `break` to break out of a loop not `return` An easy fix is to give your while loop a label and use it to break when you need to.

```
theBank: while (counter <3 && custChoice !=0) {
                 menu();
                 switch (custChoice) {
                     case 1:
                         totalPrice += priceA;
                         break;
                     case 2:
                         totalPrice += priceE;
                         break;
                     case 3:
                         totalPrice += priceL;
                         break;
                     case 0:
                         break theBank;
                     default:
                         System.out.println("You did not enter correct output");
                 }
                 counter++;
             }
System.out.println("Your total is $" + totalPrice);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers:)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your cases in your switch statement must be checking the same datatype as the variable you've assigned the switch statement. You've told switch to check `custChoice`, which you've defined as an integer, so your case statements must be integers as well. Remove to quotes from the values in the case statements will make them integers instead of strings.

Also that extra `menu()` call before and within your switch statement is messing things up too.

I added some extra print statements for showing the `total`, and the `default` case you're using would only get displayed if none of the other cases match, so I changed it to handle the unusual case instead. These are just suggestions of course.

Hope this helps.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coffee {
    public static double priceA = 1.99;
    public static double priceE = 2.99;
    public static double priceL = 3.99;
    public static double totalPrice = 0.0;
    public static int custChoice;
    public static int counter =1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (counter <= 3) {
            menu();
            switch (custChoice) {
                case 1:
                  totalPrice += priceA;
                  show_total();
                  break;
                case 2:
                  totalPrice += priceE;
                  show_total();
                  break;
                case 3:
                  totalPrice += priceL;
                  show_total();
                  break;
                case 0:
                    show_total();
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.println("Please try again");
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public static void show_total(){
        System.out.println("Your total is $" + totalPrice);
    }

    public static void menu() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        System.out.println("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);

        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("  (1) American    1.99       ");
        System.out.println("  (2) Espresso    2.99       ");
        System.out.println("  (3) Latte       3.99       ");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(" Please make a selection \n\t or enter 0 to total and quit.");
        custChoice = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```